# Terraform: How to get array/list f ARN for array of resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

How do get a list/array of ARNs for a resource created with for_each ?

```
# DynamoDB
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "terraform_state" {
  for_each = var.aws_shared_accounts

  name           = "${each.key}-terraform-state"
  read_capacity  = 5
  write_capacity = 5
  hash_key       = "LockID"
  attribute {

resource "aws_iam_role" "infra_github_role" {
  name = "TerraformBackendRole"

  inline_policy {
    name = "TerrafomBackendPolicy"

    policy = jsonencode({
      Version = "2012-10-17"
      Statement = [
        {
          Action = "*"
          Effect = "Allow"
          Resource = [
            concat(
              [aws_s3_bucket.terraform_bucket.arn, "${aws_s3_bucket.terraform_bucket.arn}/*"],
              aws_dynamodb_table.terraform_state[*].arn
            )
          ]
        },
      ]
    })
  }
}
```

Without the `aws_iam_role` I can run `terraform plan` and can see the resources

```
# aws_dynamodb_table.terraform-state["main"] will be created
  + resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "terraform-state" {

# aws_dynamodb_table.terraform-state["main-dev"] will be created
  + resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "terraform-state" {
```

The error I am receiving after adding the `aws_iam_role`

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on 03-iam.tf line 16, in resource "aws_iam_role" "infra_github_role":
  16:               aws_dynamodb_table.terraform_state[*].arn
```

Comment: What is the **full** error message?

Comment: @Marcin

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on 03-iam.tf line 16, in resource "aws_iam_role" "infra_github_role":
  16:               aws_dynamodb_table.terraform_state[*].arn
```



That was the full error. I am trying to get a list of ARNS from the list of resources

Answer (score 3):

Since you used `for_each`, to get arn values you should do:

```
values(aws_dynamodb_table.terraform_state)[*].arn
```